# How to send Text box value from Angular.js to Spring Controller?

Tags: spring, angularjs, spring-mvc

While sending data from Textbox value from Angular.js to the Spring controller, the spring controller is not able to handle the data with the name.

HTML with Angular.js:

```
    <input type="text" id="txtBox" ng-model="myForm.txtBox" ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="6"> Name <br/>

$http(
                                                    {
                                                        method : 'POST',
                                                        url : './inc',
                                                        data : names
                                                    }).
```

### Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/inc")
public class Reciver {
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String m1(@RequestParam(value="names",required=true) String names1, Model model)
{....}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add information about error you get and.

Comment: while sending data from Textbox value from Angular Js to Spring controller, spring controller not able to handle the data with the name

Comment: I think he meant like what exact error message you get.  Also, I would suggest using the browser's debug/dev tools to see exactly what is being sent in the request.

Comment: From browser the values are sending it for request. On controller side the value for the particular "names" setting to null using @RequestParam

Comment: I Changed required=false, the controller getting executed but values are not obtaining.

Comment: Answer: @Requestbody helps me on this